# Why do I get a NullReferenceException when defining a nullable owned type in EF Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm connecting to a Cosmos DB instance using Entity Framework Core 3.1.4.
I have a **Broadcast** class that contains a property of owned type **Availability**.
I don't want Availability to be mapped as an Entity. Availabilities don't have Ids, nor should they be stored in their own containers. Availabilities **are nullable**. The classes look like:

```
public class Broadcast
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Availability Availability { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class Availability
{
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}

public class BroadcastContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Broadcast> Broadcast{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Broadcast>().OwnsOne(e => e.Availability).WithOwner();
    }
}
```

So an item inside the Broadcast container in the DB should look like:

```
{
   id: "GUID",
   Name: "Foobar Broadcast",
   Availability: {
     Start: FooDate,
     End: BarDate
   }
}
```

When trying to Add a new **Broadcast** object with "Availability" set to null, this line: `modelBuilder.Entity<Channel>().OwnsOne(e => e.Availabilities).WithOwner();` throws the following exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I understand that EF Core 3.0 supports nullable Owned Types.
Am I missing something? How can I sort this out?.

Comment: It seems like you are calling a variable or method on a null value... use debugger to see if `ownsOne() gives you any result... if its null, you cant call WithOwner. You can use ?.WithOwner() to see if it helps

Comment: The debugger is unable to evalaute "ownOne()" expressions. Changed to both ?.OwnsOne and ?.WithOwner() (just in case). Same issue

Comment: I just read this article that states previous versions of EF did not allow you to have nullable navigation properties when using owned entities. This was apparently fixed in the version you are using. The example on the page does not use .WithOwner(). Can you try removing that extension. The article is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/data-points-backing-field-and-owned-entity-changes-in-ef-core-3-0#important-changes-to-owned-entities-in-ef-core-30